# I'm having an issue importing textures with a 3d model into Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am performing some research in virtual reality and we were given a 3d model made in Rhino5 with textures and everything (the model is a building). I have tried exporting it as a 3ds and fbx file type, but I am relatively new to both Rhino and Unity. My issue is that when I drag and drop the model into the unity assets of my project, and then drag from the assets to the scene, the model shows up and looks great, however no textures from the model in Rhino are visible.

I'm not sure if I should be exporting from Rhino to a specific format or if I'm exporting those formats incorrectly from Rhino.

I'm using Unity 4 and Rhino5. Thanks for your answers and your time!

Comment: Sean, this repo maybe can help you: https://github.com/lelandjobson/unify
Unify is a work in progress, but you can install in rhino and use it to transfer material and other elements properly.

Answer (score 1):

The texture is stored in a file separately from your 3D model. 
Quick steps:

1. Import your .obj or other 3D model into your unity3d assets
2. Import your .1001.png or .mtl or other texture material into your unity3D assets
3. Drag and drop your 3D model from assets into the unity3d scene
4. Click to select the object in the scene so it is outlined (mine is in orange)
5. Drag and drop your texture material from assets directly onto the selected object in the scene to apply the texture material giving the object your desired shading. The object will render the material with a shader. The object now has the qualities of the material and 3D model as one object in the scene.

For example here is a scene of a golf green. I have a 3D .obj file of the green which I select in the scene and then drag and drop my 2D material asset onto, which is a .1001.png file mapping the texture to the 3D surface. See link for image of the scene in my unity3d editor.

Image 1:
 [Unity3D object in assets. Dragged haddock.obj to get that 3D model.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqYGv.jpg)

Image 2: [Unity3D materials in assets. Dragged haddock.1001.png onto the orange outlined model to give it that shade.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AsmW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Normally models doesnt includes the textures, so you will have to import them separately into Unity and add them to the material on your model.

There might be a way to get a extra file when you export to fbx that will specify what shader and texture the materials should have when imported but i cant remember how to do that.

Comment: Not enough rep yet to upvote, but I have seen something related to this in unity documentation. I'm just trying to see if I can find a more convenient way to do this